# how to keep fraction value with fixed precision in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, sql-server-2012, apache-spark-sql

I am stuck into a very weird problem in currency calculation. I need to keep digits after point  but somehow spark is showing  flooring or ceiling value
as  example

```
My expected output is 871.25 
spark output is       871.00
```

i am getting double type value from intermediate table for this i have cast  double value to  decimal value with fixed 2 digit precision. My test code is

```
spark.sql("select cast(SUM(TRANAMT) as DECIMAL(20,2)) as Expr1 from  CMSDLG").show()
```

I am not getting which part i need to focus  here. Kindly Help me . I am using pyspark 2.0

Comment: You may use the `round()` function instead of casting.

Comment: thanks for your reply but it is not working. it remains same

Comment: First, what is the schema of the input table (SQL Server), what is the schema of the `DataFrame`, and how do you import the data?

Comment: @zero323 your  suggestion has given me some ideas. it was schema i guess. the imported data was string in remote SQLserver. but i converted it into decimal so  somehow the digit after point was cut.

Answer (score 0):

you should sum after cast...

```
spark.sql("select SUM(cast(TRANAMT as DECIMAL(20,2)) ) as Expr1 from  CMSDLG").show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it is not working. it is giving me same result

Comment: can u check query on sql?

Answer (score 0):

Use this query instead, to cast `varchar` into `decimal` and then `round` the `sum` to `2` decimal places.

```
spark.sql("select round(sum(cast(TRANAMT as decimal(65,30))),2) as Expr1 from CMSDLG").show()
```

Comment: actually i did this after your  valuable suggestion

Comment: Are you sure you have decimal values in your table?

Comment: ok fredirck i have checked that . you were right  my cmsdlg table value were string but i converted it int decimal then round it up but nothing change here is the code .you might be interested
spark.sql("select  ROUND(SUM(DecimalConvert(TRANAMT)),2) AS Expr1 from  CMSDLG ").show()